# Geoserver installed successfully but WFS doesn't work

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I installed GeoServer 2.1 RC1. It installed successfully, but when i click on WFS in services category, i got the following message.

Oops, something went wrong... 
Sorry, something unexpected happened on the server.

Here's an error report you can include in a JIRA bug report about this issue:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public org.geoserver.wfs.web.WFSAdminPage() 
        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212) 
        at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57) 
        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298) 
        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320) 
        at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234) 
        at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92) 
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)

What is wrong ? 
How can i fix this problem ?

Comment: You're unlikely to get any answers after asking 17 questions, getting 30 answers, and accepting none of them. It might be worth asking this on the GeoServer forum.

Comment: plus you'll need more details, such as how did you install it? which servlet container are you using? etc.

Comment: Can shared Marketplace return what is it’s problem can I fix it/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151328)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this same error on the latest stable version. I found that my wfs.xml file had become empty somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found it was memory related; increasing the Java heap space fixed it for me. In C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.1.0\wrapper\wrapper.conf I increased wrapper.java.maxmemory=128 to 512. Maybe that helps!